# Using recursion to iterate multiple times through rows in a dataframe - not returning the expected result

Tags: pandas, recursion

How to loop through a dataframe series multiple times using a recursive function?

I am trying to get a simple case to work and use it in a more complicated function.

I am using a simple dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'numbers': [1,2,3,4,5]
```

I want to iterate through the rows multiple time and sum the values.  Each iteration, the index starting point increments by 1.

```
def recursive_sum(df, mysum=0, count=0):
    df = df.iloc[count:]
    if len(df.index) < 2:
        return mysum
    else:
        for i in range(len(df.index)):
            mysum += df.iloc[i, 0]
        count += 1
        return recursive_sum(df, mysum, count)
```

I think I should get:

```
#Iteration 1: count = 0, len(df.index) = 5 < 2, mysum = 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 = 15
#Iteration 2: count = 1, len(df.index) = 4 < 2, mysum = 15 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 = 29
#Iteration 3: count = 2, len(df.index) = 3 < 2, mysum = 29 + 3 + 4 + 5 = 41
#Iteration 4: count = 2, len(df.index) = 2 < 2, mysum = 41 + 4 + 5 = 50
#Iteration 5: count = 2, len(df.index) = 1 < 2, mysum = 50
```

But I am returning 38.

Comment: Print the dataframe on the line above the for loop; you'll see what is happening.

Comment: To be clearer: `count` goes up, but your dataframe also gets smaller. That causes a "double" slicing/dataframe reduction effect.

Comment: OK thanks, I get it - the len(df.index) is decreasing as count increases and I'm not setting the correct upper limit of the range

Answer (score 0):

Just fixed it:

```
def recursive_sum(df, mysum=0, count=0):
    
    if(len(df.index) - count) < 2:
        return mysum
    else:
        for i in range(count, len(df.index)):
            mysum += df.iloc[0]
        
        count += 1
        return recursive_sum(df, mysum, count)
```